# Selenium FindElement() continues to search through previous html document for elements

Tags: c#, html, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

Im testing a perl website in IE11.

In the test, I find an element in the menu bar using `FindElement()`, then click the element which changes the view of the site. This obviously comes with a change in the html source code. However, when I try to find the next item to click on the page, it does not work.

By using `Debug.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.TagName("html")).GetAttribute("innerHTML"));`, I am able to see that selenium is still searching the previous page for the element I need, which does not exist on that page.. Is there a way that I can fix this issue?

Ive tried

`wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//html/frameset")));`

and

`wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("ipsm_content_frame"));`

Both timed out after 10 seconds, even though the page has loaded and even used a hard wait to wait for selenium to find the new document.

Ive also tried using

`driver.Navigate().Refresh();`

but a refresh on this specific webpage takes me back to the main page of the website..

Comment: You need to show your code

Comment: Perhaps it is taking time to load that's why you are getting same page content, you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until page element present on the page then goto perform action..:)

Comment: This is a technicality, but it doesn't matter what the website was built with. It's a website. The browser (or selenium) sees a rendered product resulting from HTML, CSS and JS. What backend technology was used to output those has no influence whatsoever on the browser. It doesn't matter if it's Perl, PHP, static HTML files, Java or anything else, just as it doesn't matter if those are served by Apache, Nginx or a PSGI server. I believe you mean that you're using the C# Selenium driver as your code does not look like valid Perl Selenium. Please remove the Perl tag, it's not relevan.

Comment: @Nate you need to wait for that element which you want instead of `frameset` and also provided `xpath` for frameset is incorrect, that's why you are getting timeout, it should be `//html/frameset`..

Comment: I believe I need to wait for the frameset to exist so I can navigate within it. Even so... `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//html/frameset")));` still timesout..

Comment: @Nate you need to wait for frame instead of frameset because selenium doesn't work with frameset..it's directly try to find frame for switching..So no need to find it...:)

Comment: This was a pretty dumb error on my part. I was stuck within a frame already, and needed to get to the default context before searching for the correct frame again.